# What's the way of error handling in my case ?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to make my Server side part to handle the errors from my 'Controllers' class to my 'Routes' class so i can show them in the Postman.

I think i should work with Promises but i don't get the way they works.
This is the code in my Controller Class,

```
async validatingWithDB(email: string, password: string) {
    await this.client.connect(async () => {
        try {
            let saltKey = await this.client.query(
                "SELECT salt FROM userinfo WHERE email=$1", [email]);

            if (saltKey.rowCount == 1) {
                let hashedLoginPassword = this.saltingValidation(password, saltKey.rows[0].salt).hash;

                let result = await this.client.query(
                    'SELECT id FROM userinfo WHERE email=$1 AND password=$2', [email, hashedLoginPassword]);

                if (result.rowCount > 1 || result.rowCount < 1) {
                   throw Error("Wrong or non existing user !");
                } else {
                    console.log("Succes Login !");
                }
            } else {
                throw Error("Wrong or non existing user !");
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
    });
  };
}

//this is in Routes Class        
app.route('/login')
        .post(async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
            try {
                if (req.body.email !== 0) {
                    if (req.body.password !== 0) {
                        await 
this.authenticationService.validatingWithDB(req.body.email, 
req.body.password)
                        res.status(200).send(new Result(
                            true, { Message: 'Login Successfully !' 
}
                        ));
                    } else {
                        throw new Error("Password too short");
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new Error("Email is too short");
                }
            } catch {
                res.status(400).send(new Result(
                    false, { Message: 'Bad request, Please try again' }, ErrorCodes.BadRequest
                ));
            }
        })
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: As an aside, use `const` instead of `let` if you do not re-assign it.